# Modify: Query which uses Group By/Having clauses, to another query which uses just Select/From/Where

Tags: sql, database

Can a query which uses Group By/Having clauses, be modified to another query which uses just Select/From/Where clauses?

```
TABLE T(a, b, c)

SELECT a, sum(c) 
FROM T 
WHERE b>10 
GROUP BY a 
HAVING sum(c)>5
```

Would appreciate it if you could explain in detail why it can(not) be done.

Comment: And also add the tag for your rdbms

Comment: Added query. Not specific to a rdbms. General Question - sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, of course, resort to using window functions only, if your specific database supports those:

```
SELECT a, s
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT a, sum(c) OVER (PARTITION BY a) s
  FROM t1
  WHERE b > 10
) t2
WHERE s > 5
```

Another option is to use correlated subqueries, which work on all databases:

```
SELECT a, s
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT a, (SELECT sum(c) FROM t t3 WHERE t1.a = t3.a AND b > 10) s
  FROM t t1
  WHERE b > 10
) t2
WHERE s > 5
```

These alternatives would yield the same result without using `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`. But either of these would be (much) slower, and I don't really see the point...

Comment: You can even do it without window functions, if you rely on correlated us queries instead.  But harder to write and performs even worse...

Comment: @RBarryYoung: True. Fixed the answer